# Instance not created Spatie Role and Permission

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-permission

I made a provider and link the repository, but I get the error:

> exception: "Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException"
> file: "../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php"
> line: 1038
> message: "Target [Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model] is not instantiable while building [App\Http\Controllers\Api\V1\User\RoleController, App\Repositories\Model\RoleRepository]."
> trace: [,…]

Namespaces:`Spatie\Permission\Models\Role;` and `Spatie\Permission\Models\Permission;`

RepositoryServiceProvider:

```
class RepositoryServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
  {
    // ...
    $this->app->bind(ModelRepositoryInterface::class, function() {
      return new PermissionRepository(new Permission);
    });
    
    // ...
  }
```

During debugging, installed `dd(new Role)`. And got this error:

> "Call to a member function connection() on null"

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Since I use the same interface, but different classes (controllers) they need to be bound like this:

```php
$this->app->when(RoleController::class)
  ->needs(ModelRepositoryInterface::class)
  ->give(function () {
    return new RoleRepository(new Role);
  });

$this->app->when(PermissionController::class)
  ->needs(ModelRepositoryInterface::class)
  ->give(function () {
    return new PermissionRepository(new Permission);
  });
```

See [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/container#contextual-binding).